# String representation of special values

Tags: scala, enums, tostring

There is [a demo](http://scastie.org/13887)

```
object Main extends App {
  object MultOp extends Enumeration {
    type MultOp = Value
    val *, /, mod, rem = Value
  }
  println(MultOp.values) // produces $times, $div, mod, rem
}
```

which undeniably demonstrates that values `*` and `/` have string representations `$times` `$div` rather than their literal sources. How can one have `*.toString` to equal `*` instead of `$mult`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the values of the enum individually and specify the string representation:

```
  object MultOp extends Enumeration {
    type MultOp = Value
    val * = Value("*")
    val / = Value("/")
    val mod = Value("mod")
    val rem = Value("rem")
  }
  println(MultOp.values) // prints MultOp.ValueSet(*, /, mod, rem)
```

[Demo](http://scastie.org/13888)

Comment: Why'd you pick an `Enumeration` rather than a `sealed trait` with child `case object`'s, Noah?

Comment: The question was using an enum so I used an enum